# Flot.js performs poorly on android webview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-webview, flot

I am using flot.js library for my graphing needs, but the performance with the android webview is **very poor**. I have this graph on the webpage, and have a need to be able to scroll up and down. *But scrolling causes what I liken to a "sloshing" effect (think water in a glass!)*.

If scroll down the flot graph "slips" upwards, and similarly if I scroll up the flot graph slides downwards before returning to its normal position. So if I scroll up and down quickly, the graph looks like its bouncing around and overlaps the title and footer (as seen below).

I have tested this on a desktop, and the problem disappears so I believe it has something to do with the canvas or webview performance.

**As anyone run into this problem before and know how I can get the flot graph to behave and stay properly aligned?**

[sample flot graph http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/1627/kpy4.png](http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/1627/kpy4.png)

Comment: Are you redrawing the graph at all once it is rendered?

Comment: No, I only call `$.plot()` once as the page is loaded up. Nothing after that.

Comment: Sounds like webview's canvas is not up to snuff, which version of android are you testing on?

Comment: I got two devices both running 4.1.2. I've tried turning on hardware acceleration, but that doesn't help at all

Comment: Are you using Flot 0.7 or 0.8.1?  Whichever one you're using, try switching to the other one, and let me know if you notice a difference.

Comment: Currently I am using flot 0.8.2 - I tried switching to both 0.7 and 0.8.1, but there was no noticeable difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Android 4.4 now uses chromium for the webviews (almost chrome, basically) and the performance is a lot better.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Perhaps not the answer I, or anyone else is looking for, but I have discovered the problem to be a combination of poor flot.js and poor android webview performance.

The android webview, as noted many times on this site, has subpar performance for intensive js applications. Turning on hardware acceleration did not help in this case.

Additionally, flot.js does not perform terribly well either. In talking to a colleague, he was able to cut the loading time needed for his application by almost a factor of 100 by writing pure javascript instead of using flot.

**TL;DR: Android WebView == Flot.js == slow**

Comment: I spent the last two days implementing on iOS, and discovered that the problem is with the android webview  - no flot lag on ios.

Comment: Android WebView == Flot.js?

Comment: == slow... as in both of them are slow? I'm not sure I understand what  you're getting at